# Is this function is bijective

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,+\infty)$ such that

$(i)$ $f$ is convex and continuous

$(ii)$ $f(t)=0$ if and only if $t=0$

$(iii)$ $\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{f(t)}{t}=0$ and $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\dfrac{f(t)}{t}=+\infty$

$(iv)$ $f$ is even

Is it possible to prove that $f$ is bijective on $[0,+\infty)$?

Thank you

Comment: @stity i found a function $f(t)=t^2$ it is not bijective on $R$ but it is bijective on $[0,+\infty[$ ? then it is not a good example i thinked that convexe and $(ii)$ imply that it is strict increasing but i don't find this property

Comment: @Vrouvrou What does even mean, in the context of non-negative domain of the function?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг $f(-t)=f(t)$

Comment: @Vrouvrou Oh, I am so sorry! I confused the domain for the range.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Injectivity: Assume $f(a) = f(b)$. Of course, $a, b > 0$. You can assume $a < b$, too, without loss of generality. There's an issue with convexity and those three points $0, a, b$.
- Surjectivity: By continuity, $f([0, +\infty))$ must be connected, i.e., an interval. Certainly $0 = f(0) \implies 0 \in f([0, +\infty))$. Now what does (iii) tell you about the codomain/range of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

### Surjectivity :

Since $f(0)=0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}=\infty$ and since $f$ is continuous, $[0,\infty[ \subseteq f([0,\infty[)$

Since $f$ is continuous, from $(ii)$ you have either $f(x) \leq 0, \forall x \in [0,\infty[ $ or $f(x)  \geq 0, \forall x \in [0,\infty[ $. As $\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}=\infty$, it can only be $f(x)  \geq 0, \forall x \in [0,\infty[ $

in the end $f([0,\infty[) = [0,\infty[$

### Injectivity :

As $f$ is convex, any local minimum is a global maximum. $f(0)=0$ is the global minimum.
Let $x,y \in [0, \infty[ $ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.

If $x=0$ then $y=0$ from $(ii)$

If $0 < x < y$, as $f$ is convex, $\forall t \in [x,y], f(t) \leq f(x)$ and there exists a local minimum $t_0$ in $[x,y]$. The only local minimum is at $x=0$ hence the contradiction and $x=y$

$f$ is surjective

Answer (score 0):

1) Injective:

$f(x)$ is convex if for

all $x_1,x_2 \in [0,\infty)$ and all $\lambda$ with $0 <\lambda <1$:

$f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2) \le $

$\lambda f(x_1)  +(1-\lambda)f(x_2).$

Let $x_1:=0$, and

$ b:=x_2$; $a: = (1- \lambda)x_2  \lt b.$

Then for  $0 <a < b$:

$f(a) \le \lambda f(0) + (1-\lambda)f(b) \lt f(b),$

$f$ is increasing , hence Injective.

2) Surjective:

$\lim_{ t \rightarrow \infty} f(t)/t =\infty$, I.e.

$f(t)/t$ is not bounded above.

Let $y \in \mathbb{R^+}$ then for  a "large enough" $t_0,$

$f(t_0)/t_0 > y$, or $f(t_0) > yt_0 > y.$

MVT : $f$ is continuous on $[0, t_0]$,

$0=f(0) <y< f(t_0), $

there is a $p \in [0,t_0]$ with $f(p) =y.$

Comment: We know nothing about the existence of $f''$

Comment: stity4. Hopefully a better answer.

Comment: I removed my downvote

Comment: stity.Thanks, never mind the downvote. You were right.